# return substring of string

Tags: c, string, memory-management

I have a large string, where I want to use pieces of it but I don't want to necessarily copy them, so I figured I can make a structure that marks the beginning and length of the useful chunk from the big string, and then create a function that reads it.

```
struct descriptor {
  int start;
  int length;
};
```

So far so good, but when I got to writing the function I realized that I can't really return the chunk without copying into memory...

```
char* getSegment(char* string, struct descriptor d) {
  char* chunk = malloc(d.length + 1);
  strncpy(chunk, string + d.start, d.length);
  chunk[d.length] = '\0';
  return chunk;
}
```

So the questions I have are:

- Is there any way that I can return the piece of string without copying it
- If not, how can I deal with this memory leak, since the copy is in heap memory and I don't have control over who will call `getSegment`?

Comment: Can you not just return `string + d.start`? Only problem would be if someone was to write to the memory. Other problem would be null terminator, so you'd probably need to manage that by passing d around with the new substring

Comment: Without damaging the original string, nothing doing.  You have to copy the sub-string without null termination into some other space to null terminate it.  You can't deal with the leak (with that interface); you have to rely on the caller to deal with the allocated memory properly.  You could define `char *getSegment(const char *source, struct descriptor d, char *output)` where the caller provides the space in the `output` parameter that must be at least `d.length+1` bytes of memory.  The caller is responsible for that memory, too, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what would be a proper interface where the called wouldn't need to deal with memory management?

Comment: @NeilLocketz "Only problem would be ... Other problem would be" golden :D

Comment: There isn't an option available in C where the caller doesn't have to manage the memory unless you have garbage collection, which isn't common and completely changes everything.  In C, you accept the responsibility for memory management. You could devise a more complex string structure including a pointer, and functions that manage such strings, and you could have a function to extract a substring from one of those strings, but the caller would still be responsible for calling the string release function.  Code in the library can't tell when the calling code has finished with what it provided.

Comment: Code should not attempt `string + d.start` as `string` is not know to point to memory that is valid up to that length - even is `string` is large, `d.start` may be greater.  Find `strlen(string)` first to avoid that.

Comment: perhaps relevant, there's a function that finds substrings in strings, check out [`strstr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

Comment: @php_nub_qq Everything is solved if you just ignore the problems :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your two questions:

1. No
2. The caller should provide buffer for the copied string
3. I would personally pass the pointer to the descrpiptor

`char* getSegment(const char* string, const char *buff, struct descriptor *d)`

Comment: if I pass the struct like I am in my example is that copying it in memory? Perhaps I'm being confused by the fact that in dynamic languages objects are always passed by reference and I see structs as equivalent for objects.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Yes, the structure is copied; no, the cost is not a major problem when there are just 2 integers in the structure.  Personally, I'd probably pass the structure, not a pointer to it.  If the structure got much bigger (contained a pointer too, for example), then I'd think about passing a pointer to the structure.  I'd also consider running performance measurements.'

Answer (score 1):

> - Is there any way that I can return the piece of string without    copying it

You're right that if you want to use the chunks in conjunction with any of the many C functions that expect to work with null-terminated character arrays, then you have to make copies.  Otherwise, adding the terminators modifies the original string.

If you're prepared to handle the chunks as fixed-length, *un*terminated arrays, however, then you can represent them without copying as a combination of a pointer to the first character and a length.  Some standard library functions work with user-specified string lengths, thus supporting operations on such segments without null termination.  You would need to be very careful with them, however.

If you take that approach, I would recommend colocating the pointer and length in a structure.  For example,

```
struct string_segment {
    char *start;
    size_t length;
};
```

You could declare variables of this type, pass and return objects of this type, and create compound literals of this type without any dynamic memory allocation, thus avoiding opening any avenue for memory leakage.

> - If not, how can I deal with this memory leak, since the copy is in heap memory and I don't have control over who will call getSegment?

Returning dynamically-allocated objects does not automatically create a memory leak -- it merely confers a responsibility on the caller to free the allocated memory.  It is when the caller fails to either satisfy that responsibility or pass it on to other code that a memory leak occurs.  Several standard library functions indeed do return dynamically-allocated objects, and it's not so unusual in third-party libraries.  The canonical example (other than `malloc()` itself) would probably be the POSIX-standard `strdup()` function.

If your function returns a pointer to a dynamically-allocated object -- whether a copied string, or a chunk definition structure -- then it should *document* the responsibility to free that falls on callers.  You must ensure that you satisfy your obligation when you call it from your own code, but having clearly documented the function's behavior, you cannot take responsibility for errors other callers may make by failing to fulfill their obligations.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I can return the piece of string without copying it

A *string* includes the terminating *null character*, so unless the part code wants is the tail, a pointer to a "piece of string" and still be a string, is not possible.

---

> how can I deal with this memory leak, since the copy is in heap memory and I don't have control over who will call getSegment?

Create temporary space with a *variable length array* (since C99 and optional supported in C11).  Good until the end of the block. At which point, the memory is released and should not be further used.

```
char* getSegment(char* string, struct descriptor d, char *dest) {
  // form result in `dest`
  return dest;
}
```

Usage

```
   char *t;
   {
     struct descriptor des = bar();
     char *large_string = foo();
     char sub[des.length + 1u]; //VLA
     t = getSegment(large_string, des, sub);
     puts(t); // use sub or t;
  }
  // do not use `t` here, invalid pointer.
```

---

Recall *size* is of concern.  If code is returning large sub-strings, best to `malloc()` a buffer  and oblige the calling code to free it when done.